# read_csv reads \, as a separator

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I know that `read_csv()` uses comma (`,`) as separator but I have a file which some of its cells has comma in their content.

In that file author used backslash comma (`\,`) to show that this comma is not a separator.

But when I read the file with `read_csv()`, it consider all commas as separator. Here is a sample row in csv file:

```
346882588,206801833,1049600263,Dzianis Dzenisiuk,5,StuckPixel\, Inc.,Feb 11\, 2010,2,3,1265846400
```

I know that there should be n columns so I read csv file line by line and remove extra commas and backslash commas.

But there should be better way.

Comment: Do you have any influence on the creation of this "csv" file? The normal way to handle this is to put non-numeric elements in quotation marks, i.e. `"StuckPixel,"`. Then the `csv` module will correctly handle the comma as part of the string.

Comment: @L3viathan No I haven't. As you said most answers on stackoverflow suggest adding quotation mark but it's not possible in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the backslash as an escape character, with the [`escapechar` option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#quoting-compression-and-file-format):

```
pandas.read_csv(fileobj_or_filename, escapechar='\\')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas, csv
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO(r'''346882588,206801833,1049600263,Dzianis Dzenisiuk,5,StuckPixel\, Inc.,Feb 11\, 2010,2,3,1265846400
... ''')
>>> df = pandas.read_csv(f, names='abcdefghij', escapechar='\\')
>>> df['f']
0    StuckPixel, Inc.
Name: f, dtype: object
>>> df['g']
0    Feb 11, 2010
Name: g, dtype: object
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want. it worked for more than a million records correctly.