# Python reading in a .txt file that is '\' backslash delimited

Tags: python, pandas, backslash, csv

I'm trying to read in a large .txt file that seems to be delimited with '\' backslashes. I know this is an escape characterand I have tried to escape it but I am getting the wrong shape when loading in. it is putting the whole row in a single variable.

Any suggestions?

I've already tried the following;

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"file_path.txt",escapechar='\\', sep = '\\')
```

and

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"file_path.txt", sep = r'\')
```

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\\')
```

Comment: Thanks @RockyLi I'm starting to think my problem is more complicated than just being \ delimited.

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Comment: @MayankPorwal version 0.23.4 also python 3.6.2

Comment: @mitch It's always possible to modify the csv on file level with python. but pandas can't read it if it's structure is corrupted (e.g. wrong col count on rows)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use

```
StringIO
```

before opening your file for reading like as shown in the link below?

[read_csv reads \, as a separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638398/read-csv-reads-as-a-separator)

Hope this can help you.